# Not able to escape \ in Java using \\

Tags: java, backslash

I have a string.

```
String invalid = "backslash escaping as <>:;%+\/"."
```

I received an error message telling me to add `\` to escape the sequence.
When I try to write this in Java I know that backslash needs to be escaped as `\\`. So I wrote it as:

```
String invalid = "backslash escaping as <>:;%+\\/\"."
```

Now this displays as `backslash escaping as <>:;%+\\/".`

The backslash is not escaping. How do I get only one backslash?

Comment: Where did you got this displayed? Your backslash is escaped correctly.

Comment: What is the final string you want to be printed?

Comment: I get this output for the second case: `backslash escaping as <>:;%+\/".` Looks OK to me.

Comment: @theVOID - i was running this in eclipse in debug mode. so in the debug mode I get the value of invalid showing as                                                                  backslash escaping as <>:;%+\\/".      So the backslash is not escaping correctly.

Comment: @miguelcobain - the final string that i want is =           backslash escaping as <>:;%+\/".

Comment: @Natix it doesn't work for me... I am not sure because everything I googled says that \\ will escape the backslash. Somehow my output has the \\ instead of \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't find a problem with your modification. This runs as expected:

```
    String invalid = "backslash escaping as <>:;%+\\/\".";
    System.out.println(invalid);

    output:
    backslash escaping as <>:;%+\/".
```

In your first example, you have a little problem:

```
\/".
```

Which I believe should be like this:

```
/\".
```

Because in the first way, you are closing the string before you want to. The part `."` is out of the String.

**Edit:**
try writing the output to a file or to a JTextField or something and see what happens, your string is correct and if you compare your output with my output it is the same. It might be an issue with your debugger (weird, but possible).

Comment: I don't think you've taken the same string as the OP had in the question, you have: 3 backslashes, while he has 2.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave Edited, sorry for that. I just had inverted the escaped quote with the slash (which is not really the problem). The problem on what exactly is he doing to get the error remains.

Comment: @Roger: the output that i am trying to get is               backslash escaping as <>:;%+\/".                                                                I just need the backslash to escape. adding another backslash in  front of it ie \\ does not seem to work for me. it just takes it as another character. but if i write just \ then it says escape the backslash with \\ . So i am not sure how to handle this.

Comment: @user2004458 try writing the output to a file or to a JTextField or something and see what happens, your string is correct and if you compare your output with my output it is the same. It might be an issue with your debugger (weird, but possible).

Comment: @Roger  you were absolutely correct... in debug mode it shows differently.. So i just imported it to a file and saw that it worked fine!!thanks so much!!!

Comment: @user2004458 Glad to help. You can accept an answer (or even write yours) to mark this question as resolved. I edited my answer with the suggestion I made.

Answer (score 0):

The second string in your post is correctly displayed. There must be something wrong with the way in which you observe the output.

Just try the simplest thing possible:

- Create a file named `Escape.java` and write this code into its contents:

  ```
  public class Escape {

      public static void main(String... args) {
          String s = "backslash escaping as <>:;%+\\/\".";
          System.out.println(s);
      }
  }
  ```
- Open a whatever command line that your OS provides and go to the folder with the said source file.
- Compile the source file:

  ```
  javac Escape.java
  ```
- And run the class file:

  ```
  java -cp . Escape
  ```
- It should give this output:

  ```
  backslash escaping as <>:;%+\/".
  ```
- ...which is exactly what you want, I believe.